# jpl.PrologException: existence_error

Tags: java, jpl

I am trying to understand how to use JPL. For this purpose I copied one of it's tests from the doc section (`swipl\doc\packages\examples\jpl\java\Time`) to eclipse and tried to run it.

If I double click the batch file, all runs well. If I run the Time class using eclipse I get

```
Exception in thread "main" jpl.PrologException: PrologException: error(existence_error(source_sink, 'time.pl'), _0)
```

I created a simple java project. Copied `Time.java` and `time.pl` to the root.
Also I created the needed Path variables and connected the `jpl.jar` to the project.

`JPL.init()` works. I fail on the if statement of this part:

```
static void test_0() {

        Query query = new Query("consult('time.pl')");

        if (!query.hasSolution()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The path to the prolog file should have the suffix of `src/`

```
Query query = new Query("consult('src/time.pl')");
```